# Can the concept of antisets be used for a neo-mechanist causal set theory?

Tags: time, physics, causation, set-theory

Background information:

1. ["Causal Approaches to Scientific Explanation," sec. 1](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/causal-explanation-science/#MechMechExpl). My takeaway here is looking at individual existential quantifications, i.e. quantifying over individual causal elements: the relevant kind of ordering (for the encompassing sets) is read off and up from specified elements.
2. ["Causal sets"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causal_sets). An overview of the program. I don't know if it counts as normal science, fringe science, or meta-science; I'm working with it at least for the sake of "toy models" in physics.
3. [*Set theory with antielements?* (MathSE question)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3325132/set-theory-with-antielements) I quote here from Noah Schweber's reply:

> ... ∪ isn't a primitive operation, it's defined in terms of ∈, and the logical associativity of ∨ directly leads to the algebraic associativity of ∪ ...

I interpret this as indicating that antisets are conceptually stable only in a sort of tensed/dynamical theory; in a timeless state, we would have *x*, its antielement *y*, the union operation (in this case, static fact) of their absorption into {*x*, *y*}, and yet then if *x* ∪ *y* = 0 = {}, we end up with {*x*, *y*} = {}, which is a contradiction. (More longwinded: we'd have *x* ∈ {*x*, *y*}, *y* ∈ {*x*, *y*}, and yet also that neither of these held "after" the element/antielement pair canceled itself out.) We could switch out the equals sign for a right arrow, granted, but again, this should be in something like a tensed logic, or rather the arrow notation thematically indicates a dynamical transition anyway.<sup>**ω**</sup>

As far as I can tell, if we install a "clock" on the interval notation, we can instead represent a noncontradictory equivalence of the (*x*, *y*)-doubleton and the empty outcome: {*x*, *y*}<sub>*t*</sub> = {}<sub>*t*+1</sub>. I haven't actually thought through that possibility much because my mind pretty quickly was diverted to the following concept:

4. Absorbing and repelling sets: sets with elements *x* such that, whenever they start out lacking elements *y*, then they gain those elements whenever the *x* are added; sets with elements *x* such that, whenever they start out having elements *y*, then they lose those elements whenever the *x* are added.

Then we could go on to "elements that, when repelled, are repelled into the set-theoretic 'ether' **or** which (necessarily or not) end up in some other specific sets," etc.

Suppose, then, one made toy models of physical charge relations (**not** the matter-antimatter relation directly, not even the electrical-charge function, but just a charge function "*in general*") in terms of sets like the above. Since we are not (clearly) talking about united all-encompassing laws imposing order "from the top down" but simply indicating a fairly specific kind of dynamical set relation, are we working with a causal set theory that is also neo-mechanist in character? (Note that we are not claiming the nonexistence of top-down laws, and in fact one might style the *type* of antielement dynamics as a top-down law. But if I wrote out the intended quantifiers for the above, I would be mostly using the existential quantifier on individual, relatively local variables, rather than the universal quantifier in tandem with conditional arrows.)

---

<sup>**ω**</sup>Suppose, for example, that antielements never run out in the well-founded transet. If we take the universal transet over all element-antielement pairs, the outcome would be the equivalent of a set both completely empty and completely universal, or a *multiset* with |ORD|-many copies of the empty set inside it. One might take this for a novel illustration of the set-theoretic multiverse (i.e. "there is a concept of sets in terms of element/antielement pairs that cannot be composed into a one individual stable universe"), or one could take it to show that the concept of antisets goes beyond a theory of timeless pure sets by default, or one might think of probably a bunch of other things I haven't myself thought of yet.